# View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function received `undefined` Make sure to start component names with a capital letter

Tags: react-native, material-ui

While i am using MUI library in react native they give me a error like [ERROR  Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.] this as I am not using any style in the code`

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import externalStyle from './Style/externalStyle'

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Button style={style.Text}>Contained</Button>
      <Button variant="contained" disabled>
        Disabled
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" href="#contained-buttons">
        Link
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3obt.png). can anyone please solve my problem. [Error show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf8AO.png)

I refer some video and try external style that is also not use they give me same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View config getter callback for component \`style\` must be a function received \`undefined\` Make sure to start component names with a capital](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77211889/view-config-getter-callback-for-component-style-must-be-a-function-received-u)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the file name. You just have to rename your `externalStyle.js` file to `ExternalStyle.js` and update it everywhere you have used `externalStyle.Text` to `ExternalStyle.Text`.

The reason this is caused is because `react-native` wants you to name classes and functions with starting with capital letters and variables with camelCase.

Happy coding :)

Comment: In your updated code, you need to update your import statement and modify your `style` attribute inside `Button` component to `style={ExterStyle.Text}`

Comment: I hope that helps. If not please let me know what exactly is `Text` property doing in your `ExternalStyle.js` file (or a screenshot or code snippet would also work) and I'll try to help you out

Comment: Still they didn't work

Comment: I just used external style but i want to use internal style

Comment: I guess @Sam Sycamore is right then. MUI is probably not compatible with react native.. You can use `react-native-paper` if you're looking for pre-built components. The components from paper are extremely customisable and even without any customisation also work wonderfully. So I suggest you give it a try instead

Comment: I am telling you definitively that Material UI is not compatible with React Native. I work for the company that maintains Material UI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicate of [View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function received `undefined` Make sure to start component names with a capital](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77211889/view-config-getter-callback-for-component-style-must-be-a-function-received-u/77218024#77218024)

Material UI is not compatible with React Native.