# View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function received `undefined` Make sure to start component names with a capital

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, mui-x

While I am using MUI library in react native they give me an error:

> ERROR Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component style must be a function (received undefined). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

I am not using any style in the code.

````js
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Button >Contained</Button>
      <Button variant="contained" disabled>
        Disabled
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" href="#contained-buttons">
        Link
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

[The error thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNM3z.png)

What should I do?
````

Answer (score 0):

Material UI is not compatible with React Native—it's only for ReactJS.